# How to MVVM Kendo UI widgets further?

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, viewmodel

Been working with Kendo UI widgets for a while, and currently looking to MVVM my code further. so far, i managed to do this only on specific widget properties that use 'source', 'value', 'text' etc. and on events (which are the supported MVVM bindings, according to the documentation). but what if i want to MVVM other properties such as a window title, dropdown width, or even chart data-series?

i don't see example for this in the documentation and i'm wondering if this is possible at all? natively by kendo or via a 3rd party framework such as Angular?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but yea, hard to find...this is some of mine examples that i use with Kendo MVVM.

Window:

```
<div id="active-call-window">
    <div id="active-call"
         style="top: 75px"
         data-role="window"
         data-visible="false"
         data-enabled="true"
         data-modal="true"
         data-resizable="false"
         data-width="98%"
         data-height="88%"
         data-position="{top: '25px', left: '1%'}"
         data-bind="events: { open: onWindowOpened, close: onWindowClose }">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 padding-less" data-template="active-call-main-template" data-bind="source: this"></div>
            <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="active-call-main-template">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <span>Call from</span>
                    <span>#= activeCall.number #</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4">
                    <span>Called service</span>
                    <span class="active-call-main-header">#= activeCall.serviceName #</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2">
                    <span>Status</span>
                    <span class="active-call-main-header" style="color: #= activeCall.statusColor #">#= activeCall.status == 'ON_HOLD' ? 'ON HOLD' : activeCall.status#</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
                    <span>Duration</span>
                    <span class="active-call-main-header">#= Util.toHHMMSS(activeCall.durationInSeconds) #</span>
                </div>
            </script>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var ActiveCall = (function () {
var _init = function () {
    //Bind it to element id, in that element kendo observable object will be available
    kendo.bind($('#active-call-window'), _viewModel);
};

//Make kendo observable object
var _activeCallViewModel = function () {
    return kendo.observable({
        activeCall: {},
        isMaximized: true,
        isMinimized: false,
        //Can be triggered anywhere in js
        openWindow: function () {
            //Get kendo window instance
            var window = $('#active-call');
            //Open kendo windows
            window.getKendoWindow().open();
            //Remove title section
            window.getKendoWindow().title(false);
        },
        //Event triggered on window open, check html
        onWindowOpened: function (e) {
            //console.log("test");
        },
        closeWindow: function () {
            $('#active-call').getKendoWindow().close();
        },
        onWindowClose: function () {

        },
        minimizeWindow: function () {
            if (this.get('isMaximized')) {
                this.changeWindowWidth(48, 51);
                this.set('isMinimized', true);
                this.set('isMaximized', false);
            }
        },
        maximizeWindow: function () {
            if (this.get('isMinimized')) {
                this.changeWindowWidth(98, 1);
                this.set('isMinimized', false);
                this.set('isMaximized', true);
                $('#cuc-active-calls').css('z-index', '12');
            }
        },
        isWindowOpened: function () {
            var window = $('#active-call').getKendoWindow();

            return !window.element.is(':hidden');
        },
        //Set object that is represented on view, when this change html will change too
        setActiveCall: function (call) {
            this.set('activeCall', call);
        },
        //Get kendo window class and css wraper, with this you dynamically change visualizations of window
        changeWindowWidth: function (pctWidth, pctLeft) {
            $('#active-call').getKendoWindow().wrapper.addClass('active-call-k-window');
            $('#active-call').getKendoWindow().wrapper.css({
                width: pctWidth ? pctWidth + '%' : '97%',
                left: pctLeft ? pctLeft + '%' : '2%'
            });
        },
    });
};

var _viewModel = _activeCallViewModel();

//Bind events, for example when object 'activeCall' changes catch that event and do something
_viewModel.bind('change', function (e) {
    //bind changes
});

//expose initialization and observable object publicly,
//after init you cant in any .js file call ActiveCall.viwModel.closeWindow() or any other function/property (ActiveCall.viwModel.set('isMaximized', true)) 
return {
    init: _init,
    viewModel: _viewModel
}
})();
```

**NOTE:**
You need to set values like this: `this.set('name','John);` not like this t`his.name = 'John';`

Hope it helps!